# How to signal a custom attribute in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, custom-attribute

For a binding, I can use `signal` in case the value is externally updated. How about a custom attribute?

I have the following `data-language` custom attribute:

```
import { customAttribute, autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { LanguageService } from "./language";

@autoinject
@customAttribute("data-language")
export class LanguageCustomAttribute {

    private value: string;

    constructor(
        private element: Element,
        private languageService: LanguageService) { }

    public bind() {
        var e = $(this.element);
        e.html(this.languageService.getText(e.attr("data-language")));
    }

}
```

This custom attribute is globally registered using

```
  aurelia.use
      .standardConfiguration()
      .globalResources("./components/language/data-language");
```

Now assume user can change a language at runtime (and the result of `this.languageService.getText` would change). How can I send a signal so all `[data-language]` elements are updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what the Aurelia I18N plugin does as well using the EventAggregator to update the custom attributes value on the fly when noticed. [See this Aurelia Discourse discussion](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/signal-aurelia-custom-attribute/1461/2) for detailed explanation